# commons-beanutils: if set method return is this model, can't get writeMethod

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

```
private long payActualMoney; 

public long getPayActualMoney() {
  return this.payActualMoney;
}

public TAllocate setPayActualMoney(long payActualMoney) {
  this.payActualMoney = payActualMoney;
  setPayActualMoneyIsSet(true);
  return this;
}
```

PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors not return payActualMoney 's writeMethod,and return an property 'setPayActualMoney'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your setter return type isn't **void**.

Comment: yes,but this code generated by thrift ,I can't change this . how can support it

Comment: Some libraries require that your getter/setter methods conform to the JavaBean Specification, otherwise not supported.   You may have to lookup those types of methods using Reflection yourself.

Comment: can I disable beanutils return type valid?

Comment: Not that I am aware.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: As of commons-beanutils version 1.9.x you can add an introspector that will accept setters that don't return void (e.g. setters that return `this`). To do so have: `PropertyUtils.addBeanIntrospector(new FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector())` somewhere before your call to `PropertyUtils.setProperty(..` and it will work (using non-void returning setters).